# Restart gui (GTK) on Raspberry Pi from remote shell

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gui

I have a script that kills the biggest lxpanel task on my Raspberry Pi, but occasionally it kills both tasks, which kills the menu system on the GUI.

I am using VNC to view the desktop and I have putty to create remote shells.  I intend to make my script a crontab job, but that means that it does not have a "display:", so "lxpanelctl restart" will not work (cannot open display:).

So, how do I restart the GUI from a crontab job which is like doing it from a remote putty shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron doesn't have its `DISPLAY` variable set, so it simply doesn't know which display it is to restart lxpanel in.

Simplest solution:

```
# lxpanel restarts every day at 03:00
00 3 * * * export DISPLAY=":0.0" && lxpanelctl restart
```